# Optimization - how to store "bits" in memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, memory-management, bit-manipulation

I'm a newbie in Python and I have a problem with storing information. I've got a task from my 'mentor' and I don't know how to do that.
I have array with numbers 0 and 1, e.g.

```
a=[1,1,1,0]
```

I know that's integers, but he told I should keep it as bits. 
I was trying to convert my variable to number e.g:

`a = 14` and then `ab = bin(14).`

But when I'm using `sys.getsizeof()` ab is bigger than a.
I was trying to use `bytearray()` but I don't understand it, too.
I was thinking that I know how a computer works, but that makes me confused.

How should I keep bits? What should I use? What should I read to understand it? and how to measure how big is my variable (`sys.getsizeof()` is okay for that? Or should I write it to a binary file?).
We doing it to optimize memory.

Comment: You don't have to make the number become literal bits. I think what your teacher meant is that you should let the numbers represent bits and use bitwise operations on them. And if you need to view the numbers as binary you can just convert each integer in the array to its binary representation using `bin()`.

Comment: Sound interesting, but I'm starting from array of numbers 0 and 1 and he told that I should store it as bits. After that I should read "one machine word" to memory. That's sounds too crazy for me...

Comment: What exactly is his definition of a "machine word"? Different computers have different word sizes. Did you give you a specific value like 4 bits or 8 bits? And how exactly does he want the numbers stored as bits? Does he want to convert them to their bit representation? Does he want to write them to a binary file? What I recommend you do is meet with your teacher and discuss your questions with him/her. They'll be able to tell you exactly what they're looking for.

Comment: I was trying but it's experiment and he told that he want to me think about it... Good question about size of machine word, he was telling that's 32 or 64 bits.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the goal, but here's a guess:

```
def convert(bits):
    val = 0
    for bit in bits:
        val = (val << 1) | bit
    return val

a = [1, 1, 1, 0]
ab = convert(a)
print(ab, bin(ab))  # -> 14 0b1110
```

The result stored in `ab` is a single Python integer, which have varying lengths depending on how many bits are required to hold the number. The code above will handle any number of bits (but you could put a limit on it).